# Proving the inscribed angle theorem

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, circles

I need to prove that a circle's inscribed angle is 1/2 of the arc it intercepts. I am given that one of the chords making up the angle is the diameter. I have an entire project to do based off of this proof, so I really need to prove this.[image]

Comment: Do you know that an inscribed angle is half the central angle when *both* intercept the same arc? And do you know that an arc (measure) equals the central arc that intercepts it? Well, there you go...:)

Comment: Have you checked [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle)?

Comment: That's what I am supposed to prove

Comment: The angle AOB has the same measure as arc AB.  What is the measure of angle AOC then?  What sort of triangle is AOC and what does that mean for the measures of angles ACO and OCA?

Answer (score 1):

The case you drew is perhaps the easiest one:

$\;\Delta AOC\;$ is isosceles, with $\;AO=OC\implies \angle ACO=\angle CAO\;$, and since

$\;\angle AOB\;$ is an external angle to triangle $\;\Delta AOC\;$ , then it equals the sum of the two triangle's

angles whose vertex it doesn't share, thus

$$\angle AOB=\angle CAO+\angle ACO=2\angle ACO$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If $\angle AOB=2\alpha$, then what is  $\angle AOC$? $\angle ACO$?